# How to calculate$ \int_{0}^{Q}F(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory

Assume $X$ is a continuous random variable with CDF $F(\cdot)$, we want to calculate $$\int_{0}^{Q}F(x)dx, $$ where $Q$ is given and a constant. Is there any method to simplify the fomula or remove the integration.

It is a general function and I do not know the exact form of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to remove the integration from the formula without more information about $F$. If you wish, you can express $F$ as an antiderivative of a PDF $f$ and rewrite the function as a double integral. This is going the opposite direction from what you wanted, though. Are you sure you are supposed to be integrating a CDF?

Comment: Yes, when we need to calculate the expected profit for newsvendor problem with general-distributed demand. We need to calculate the integral.

Comment: @oneuser Perhaps you can ask the more specific question as a new question on math.stackexchange.com to see if you get a more satisfying answer. Unfortunately, in this generality, there's nothing else that can be said.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.